# Why doesn't my script tag reference my .js file?

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a simple webapp using Flask. When referencing my functions.js as src in the script tag, the app doesn't recognize it. My current file arrangement goes like this:

.     
                                                                                                                  ├── README.md  
                                                                                                         ├── **pycache**       
                                                                                                  │   └── application.cpython-39.pyc  
                                                                                    ├── app.db          
                                                                                                    ├── application.py   
                                                                                                   ├── functions.js    
                                                                                                    ├── requirements.txt  
                                                                                                  ├── static     
                                                                                                         │   ├── favicon.ico 
                                                                                                   │   └── styles.css  
                                                                                                    ├── templates   
                                                                                                    │   ├── control.html   
                                                                                                 │   ├── index.html    
                                                                                                  │   ├── layout.html    
                                                                                                 │   └── login.html

And my html reference goes like this:

```
<script src="/functions.js"></script>
```

The weird thing is, html recognizes the files inside the /static folder, and when I put the .js inside it and change the path, it's referenced, but when I make a new folder named js, put funtions.js inside it, and change the path (Which would be /js/functions.js), it isn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `src` attribute has to be a URL.

The webserver has to translate that URL into a set of instructions to read the file.

It is configured to do that for `/static`. This is a traditional place to put static files.

It is not configured to do that for any other path. If `/functions.js` worked then `/application.py` would and your server-side code would suddenly be public.

Keep your static files in the static folder. That is what it is for.